# How to check if a daemon service is running via Cron job or script?

Tags: php, python, bash, cron, daemon

How can I set up a cron job to monitor multiple PIs (via SSH) that are running the same daemon script (service)?

I was thinking of using a cron job to monitor the service status and write to a file on my server if the status of the service is active or inactive, and then I can later use the contents of that file to display the results of the Cron job onto a web page (but that is for me to figure out later).

I'm open to other options if someone can figure out an easier way using a different tool, E.g. bash script, python script, PHP etc,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question

> How to check if a daemon service is running

in RHEL/CentOS v4.x/5.x/6.x and Fedora Linux (older version) Verify Cron Service
You can simply use any one of the following command to see if crond is running or not, enter:

```
$ pgrep crond
```

OR

```
$ service crond status
```

Sample outputs:

```
# crond (pid 4370) is running...
```

If it is not running type the following two command to start crond:

```
$ chkconfig crond on
$ service crond start
```

Verify cron is running by viewing log file, enter:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/cron
```

A note about CentOS/RHEL v7.x+ and latest version of Fedora Linux
You need to use the following command to find out if the crond is running or not:

```
$ systemctl status crond.service
```

Sample outputs:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-05-19 14:53:32 EDT; 3min 7s ago
 Main PID: 1292 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           â””â”€1292 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

If not running configure the crond service to start automatically on boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable crond.service
$ sudo systemctl start crond.service
```

A note about Debian / Ubuntu Linux (older version) Cron service
On a Debian and Ubuntu Linux cron logs its action logged to the syslog facility i.e. use /var/log/messages file:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Find out if cron daemon is running or not, enter:

```
$ pgrep cron
```

If not running start it, enter:

```
$ update-rc.d cron defaults
$ /etc/init.d/cron start
```

A note about Debian Linux v8.x+ and latest version of Ubuntu Linux
The syntax is as follows to check if the cron service is running or not:

```
# systemctl status cron
```

Sample outputs:

```
â— cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-05-19 11:49:32 IST; 12h ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1053 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           â”œâ”€1053 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           â””â”€3020 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /var/log/atop/atop_20150520 600
```

If not running configure the crond service to start automatically on boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable cron.service
$ sudo systemctl start cron.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many answers (including on this page too) but none of the code worked for nginx.

I don't know exactly why the codes didn't start the nginx service even if some of them identified it to be down successfully.

The only one which I found to be working was this.

**Adding a bash script file with code:**

(i added the code to file `/opt/nginxstartifdown.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

service=$@
/bin/systemctl -q is-active "$service.service"
status=$?
if [ "$status" == 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    /bin/systemctl start "$service.service"
fi
```

**Adding this to cron job** (`sudo crontab -e`)

```
* * * * * /opt/nginxstartifdown.sh nginx > /dev/null
```

reference from: (not my website, not my content)
https://maslosoft.com/kb/watching-for-service-with-cron/

Sharing it so that it may help someone looking for turning on nginx whenever it goes off.